# Join two PHP arrays randomly?

Tags: php, arrays, random

One array is

```
Array ( 
[0] => love 
[1] => home 
[2] => google 
[3] => money 
)
```

And another is

```
Array ( 
[0] => 111
[1] => 222
[2] => 333 
[3] => 444 
[4] => 555 
[5] => 666 
[6] => 777 
[7] => 888 
)
```

I want to make 3th array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[love] => 111
[google] => 222
[home] => 333 
[love] => 444 
[google] => 555 
[money] => 666 
[money] => 777 
[google] => 888 
)
```

So, it should randomly select some of elements from 1st array and join them to all elements in 2nd.

Comment: Your result is not possible - there are duplicate array keys there.

Comment: Your final array isn't actually a valid array.  You can't have more than one entry with the same key.

Comment: Your output array has multiple copies of each key.  You can't do that, as you'll just keep overwriting the same key.

Comment: Having several times the same key in the 3rd array is not possible in the way you described. It would just overwrite the previous value for that index. 
Maybe its best if you first describe what/why you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in all the comments, your final array is not possible. 
What you could do would be something like this:

```
finalArray = Array (
  [0] => [google] => 111
  [1] => [home] => 222
  [2] => [google] => 333
  ...
)
```

You could achvieve this like this (use [array_rand](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php) for random array value):

```
$array3 = array();
foreach ($array2 as $element) {
    $array3[] = array($element => $array1[array_rand($array1)]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, to create such an Array is not possible, but you can do something like this:

```
$words = array( 'love', 'home', 'google', 'money' );
$numbers = array( 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888 );
$result = array();
foreach($words as $word){
    $result[$word] = array();
}
$wordsmax = count($words) - 1;
foreach($numbers as $number){
    $result[$words[rand(0,$wordsmax)]][] = $number;
}
```

This could output something like:

```
Array (
    [love] => Array (
            [0] => 222
            [1] => 888
        )
    [home] => Array (
            [0] => 555
            [1] => 666
            [2] => 777
        )
    [google] => Array (
            [0] => 333
        )
    [money] => Array (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 444
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$numbers = Array ( 
[0] => 111
[1] => 222
[2] => 333 
[3] => 444 
[4] => 555 
[5] => 666 
[6] => 777 
[7] => 888 
);

$text = Array ( 
[0] => love 
[1] => home 
[2] => google 
[3] => money 
);
$new_array = array();
foreach($numbers as $value){
   $new_array
}
```

I was just about to try this then I remembered.  Array keys have to be **unique** -- In other words you **cannot** have 2 elements in the array with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

`array_combine` will use one array for the keys and one for the values: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

```
$keys = array ( 
  'love',
  'home',
  'google',
  'money' 
);
$vals = array ( 
 111,
 222,
 333, 
 444, 
 555, 
 666, 
 777, 
 888
);
$output = array_combine($keys, $vals);
```

This is not random, though.  Random requires a loop:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($keys as $k) {
 $output[$k] = $vals[array_rand($vals)];
}


   /* output: 
Array
(
    [love] => 666
    [home] => 555
    [google] => 222
    [money] => 777
)
*/
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/7c55LvXg

Another approach, using `shuffle` to mix the arrays up.  This seems to yield the nicest results:

```
shuffle($keys);
shuffle($vals);
$output = array();
while (count($keys) > 0 && count($vals) > 0) {
  $key = array_pop($keys);
  $output[$key] = array_pop($vals);
}

/* output: 
Array
(
    [love] => 555
    [money] => 777
    [home] => 444
    [google] => 333
)
*/
```

Codepad for the last one: http://codepad.org/BpM8RzD3