# How to insert randomly entries of an array in another array

Tags: php, arrays, random

Let's says I have this array :

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

And this array :

```
$letters = array('A','B','C');
```

I want to put `$letters` entries inside `$numbers` randomly. I don't care about the order of `$letters`, but I want `$numbers`to keep the order. The goal is to have this kind of array :

```
$randomLettersInNumbers = array(1, 'B', 2, 3, 'A', 4, 'C', 5);
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Huh... No :/ Sorry, does my question is too large... ? I believe I have to use array_splice but all my attempts end with a completely huge and incomprehensible function (which doesn't work).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376220/how-to-combine-two-arrays-randomly-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377433/join-two-php-arrays-randomly

Comment: seems like PHP doesn't have an arbitrary insert function for an array, which makes it a mess to write. in python it's as easy as: `[numbers.insert(random.randint(0, len(numbers) - 1), letter) for letter in letters]`

Comment: @alfasin no duplicate. One array should remain in order versus one being randomized and randomly inserted. That's quite a difference to the referenced questions. As is the possible solution.

Comment: @SamuelHerzog good argument :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
foreach($letters as $letter)
{
    array_splice($numbers, rand(0, count($numbers)), 0, $letter);
}
print_r($numbers);
```

Comment: If you are using class objects and you want to insert just one item you still have to provide it as an **array with one element**, otherwise it will be forcefully cast to an array (each property will be a key).